# How can I add another MATCH condition if CASE is such and such in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, conditional-statements, cypher, case

I have a query and I want to add another MATCH condition to it if an attribute is certain value.

Something like this: **CASE WHEN type.character = 'Odborný' THEN MATCH (teachingSubject)<-[]-(achievedField) ELSE TRUE**

Full query is here:

````
MATCH (teachingSubject:Subject {code: "M"})-[:IS_PART_OF]->(teachingSubjectGroup:SubjectGroup)<-[:QUALIFIES_FOR]-(qualification)
MATCH (achievedTitle:EducationTitle {name: "Mgr."})<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(type:EducationType)
MATCH (achievedField:CollegeArea {name: "Stavebnictví"})<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(type)
CASE WHEN type.character = 'Odborný' THEN MATCH (teachingSubject)<-[]-(achievedField) ELSE TRUE
MATCH (toStudy:EducationType)<-[:COMBINES]-(qualification)-[:COMBINES]->(type) WHERE toStudy <> type
RETURN toStudy```

How can I do this legally?
````

Comment: look at subqueries: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/

Answer (score 0):

Or patter comprehensions that compute a list of data

```
CASE WHEN type.character = 'Odborný' 
THEN [ (teachingSubject)<--(achievedField) | achievedField] 
ELSE [] END
```